# How to create recurly success url?

Tags: php, recurly

I did not find required information to create recurly success url manually.

```
http://example.com/index.php/register/KNhiaz?act=reg&account_code={{account_code}}&plan_code={{plan_code}}
```

I do not know how to get account_code, when i am subscribe user with recurly php client

```
// Specify the minimum subscription attributes: plan_code, account, and currency
                $subscription = new Recurly_Subscription();
                $subscription->plan_code = $plan_code;
                $subscription->currency = 'USD';

                // Create an account with a uniqid and the customer's first and last name
                $subscription->account = new Recurly_Account(uniqid());
                $subscription->account->first_name = esc_attr( $_POST['first_name'] );
                $subscription->account->last_name = esc_attr( $_POST['last_name'] );

                // Now we create a bare BillingInfo with a token
                $subscription->account->billing_info = new Recurly_BillingInfo();
                $subscription->account->billing_info->token_id = $_POST['recurly_token'];

                // Create the subscription
                $subscription->create();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer. After some debugging i found that account code will be my email id which i will get from user from custom recurly form. 
Email of user is important because by this email id user will get time to time notification from recurly for renewal, invoice etc. I personally think it is good to ask user for email id for future communication.

Read here:
https://docs.recurly.com/hosted-payment-pages#account_code__username

Comment: Keep in mind that email address is only the account_code if no other variable is passed into that parameter